# Delphi 7 - perform operation if (var) = 1,3,5,7 etc

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

my Delphi 7 is very basic so I apologise in advance if this seems like a dumb question.
I want my code to do something if a number is either 1 or 3 or 5 etc etc. or else do something else if it is 2 or 4 or 6 etc etc.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Tony

Comment: Can you show the code that you have tried? I am asking because the solution should be pretty obvious, so I suspect we'd need to explain starting from a particular misconception of yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `odd()` function.

It returns `true` for 1,3,5,7, and it returns `false` for 2,4,6.

**Example**

```
var
  x: Integer;
....
x := ...;
if odd(x) then
  writeln('x is odd')
else
  writeln('x is even')
```

More generally if you wanted to test for divisibility by a number other than two you would use the `mod` operator. The returns the remainder of an integer division. So

```
if x mod 3 = 0 then
  writeln('x is divisible by 3')
else
  writeln('x is not divisible by 3')
```

Comment: @davidheffernan: thanks for the extra tips that you've added. Stackoverflow should award points for helpful edits :)